# How to manually unlock user with SimpleMembership provider MVC 4.0?

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

Is there a way to manually unlock a user with the SimpleMembership provider?

```
   if(WebSecurity.IsAccountLockedOut(model.UserName,4,10000)) {
         return RedirectToAction("LockedAccount");
    }
    websecurity.unlockuser(); -> any functions like this
```

Within the time limit an admin wants to unlock the user account.  Is there any possibilities?
Can anyone give the correct suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a method in **WebSecurity** to unlock the account.  But you could try using the [SimpleMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.unlockuser%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) like this.

```
var membership = (WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
membership.UnlockUser(model.UserName);
```

Comment: This throws a `NotSupportedException`.